# Skype sound alarm until I read the message

Tags: windows, audio, skype, skype-for-business, alarm

I need a way (could be a software) that makes some noise when I receive a message on my Skype (desktop).

Sometimes I'm away from my computer and I can't listen to the regular sound when I receive a message. I need something that only stops when I actually read the message. Something like when somebody is calling me.

I need it for regular Skype and Skype for business.

Comment: If this behavior isn't built-in to Skype, this will likely be difficult to accomplish. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to change the default alarm sound to the same used for calling. It hasn't worked properly because it is still to short to be noticed from distance. Another approach I tried was to download a software that rings an alarm when an application is notifying something. I couldn't find such software.

Comment: Because the methods applications use for notifications vary widely, such an application as you are looking for likely does not exist. Perhaps it may some day as more developers build their notifications into the Windows 10 Notification tray, which could probably be hooked into and modified by an enterprising dev.

Answer (score 0):

That´s a nice idea, however out of the box this isn´t possible. But feel free to share your feature request on the [official Skype for Business Feedback Platform from Microsoft](https://www.skypefeedback.com/forums/299913-generally-available).

Other users could vote for it and it would be easier for Microsoft can find the good ideas and consider to implement that.

However this isn´t a direct solution for you which can be used now.